# Plotting a contour corresponding to exact data points in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

[image]

I have these time, x values and temperatures as 3 columns of my data.

Time varies from 0-40
X varies from 400-1300
and temperature has huge variations from 0-10^5.

I have loaded all my data into variables and plotted this.

This is my script for this plot.

```
clear all; close all; clc;
load temperature.txt;
time = temperature(:,1);
x = temperature(:,2);
temperature_system = temperature(:,3);
% Removing outliers with data value below 41.96 percentile
pos = temperature_system < prctile(temperature_system,41.96);
time(pos) = [];
x(pos) = [];
temperature_system(pos) = [];

% Removing data values above 97 percentile
pos = (temperature_system > prctile(temperature_system,97));
time(pos) = [];
x(pos) = [];
temperature_system(pos) = [];

X1 = [time x];

% This function crates an interpolation of the data points
F = scatteredInterpolant(X1,temperature_system);
x1 = linspace(400,max(x),100);
x2 = linspace(min(time),max(time),100);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x2,x1);
Z = F(X,Y);
f1 = figure(1);
set(f1,'renderer','zbuffer');
contourf(X,Y,Z);
shading flat;
colorbar;
```

The problem as you can see is, my values on the y axis vary from 400 onwards but I see all these values below 400 colored blue which should not be there. How can I remove this.

Please note that the file is around 50 MB so I cannot upload it here.

Please suggest a few things to remove this blue region.

Comment: what do you mean by "exact"? Are you sure you want to use `countour`, and not `pcolor` or `imagesc`? You should include a screenshot about what you want and some example data to play with. Maybe `plot3` is also what you want?

Comment: I thought that a contour plot was supposed to show lines where all data have the same value. I would say this basically requires that you have a set of 2-D data which somehow can be said to cover an area (and which can be interpolated to a 2-D grid). So why is `contour` not good enough for this? You said you have interpolated the data, so I assume you can create a proper grid required by `contour`.

Comment: @patrik I have just now changed the post and added the plot also please have a look and offer your suggestion. And no the data is 3 dimensional in nature that's why I was able to interpolate the data and obtain a functional form for it. I have added the script as well. Please have a look and offer your suggestion.

Comment: @AnkitMishra Please do not edit answers with your own result and further questions. Instead comment on what does not work and edit the question. Further the `set(q,'Limits', []);` is not meant to work. You are supposed to set the limits you require.

Comment: @patrik Yes of course I changed the argument for the Limits option. I am getting this error "The name 'Limits' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'colorbar'". Can you something else.

Comment: @AnkitMishra it is better to keep this thread under the answer, so write next comment there. Apart from this, which version of matlab are you using? The OP works for 2014b, but these properties changes from time to time. Use `get()` on the handle to find the properties you can edit. There may also be a function to set the limits. There is also possible to find public properties by typing `q.` and tapping tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably not to modify the data too much, but to modify the plot. I cannot recreate your data, but to have some demo data I have used the built in `peaks` and to imitate the "non-plot-area" I have set datapoints smaller than 0 to 0. You will probably understand when you see it. Still, the solution requires some modification of the plot.

Since I do not want to plot the smallest points I assign the colormap data to `cmap`. This will allow me to modify the colormap. Since `cmap(1,:)` is the bottom color I set this to white. Then I set the colormap with `colormap(cmap)`. I will have one color less in the used spectra, but I see this as a resonably small loss. But now I have some white at the bottom which is ugly. To remove this I rescale the colorbar by setting the lower limit to 0.2 (`set(q,'Limits',[0.2,8]);`). In case you use the debugger (or use comments or something) to go through this step by step you will notice that a lower limit of 0.1 is not enough to remove the white. It is possible to calculate where the white disappears more exactly, but often this kind of things are not necessary.

```
function demo()
[x,y,z]=peaks;
z(z<0) = 0;
contourf(x,y,z);
q=colorbar;
cmap = colormap;
cmap(1,:) = [1,1,1];
colormap(cmap);
set(q,'Limits',[0.1,8]); % or use ylim(q,[0.1,8])
set(q,'Limits',[0.2,8]); % or use ylim(q,[0.2,8])
```

[image]

You will probably need to do other modifications as well, such as set the `'CLim'` property in the figures axes (can be done with `caxis()` as well). This will set the lower limit on the colorbar to whatever you decide (400?). After that the same method as above can be directly applied unless you want something more.

It is hard to know exactly what you are after since this kinds of problem often is highly specific, but this should help you enough on the way to help you get through.

Good Luck and in case of unclarities, please comment.

**EDIT**
I have noticed that `'Limits'` is not a property of colorbar for older versions. However, the function `ylim()` is still working for both pre 2014b and post 2014b. This means that this one can be an alternative. Using this function may lower the burden of maintenance when upgrading to new Matlab versions

Comment: @AnkitMishra Do you have a property named `YLim` or something like that? I think this was one of the changes in 2014b. For the record, The problem is that `Limits` property does not exist in 2013b. This example is for 2014b or later I think.